# Issue during pagination

Tags: php, url, pagination, append

I have a pagination method that is working to a point.  If I navigate beyond page 2, or use my Previous or Next button, my current page and total page variables are appended to the URL, resulting in something like this:

```
http://localhost/project/profile.php?s=0&p=2&s=1&p=2&select_genre=Sci-Fi&select_length=1-25&query=Submit
```

Notice the extra s and p assignments

$s defines the starting page
$p defines total pages

Is there a way to prevent the values of $s and $p from appending to the URL?

I'm sure the problem is in how I carry the GET values across the pages in the URL below, I'm not sure how to correct it:

```
if($pages > 1)
{
    echo '<br /><p>'; //Add some extra space

    $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

    //If it's not the first page, make a PREV button

    if($current_page != 1)
    {
        echo '<a href=profile.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&' . http_build_query($_GET) . '"> Previous</a> ';
    }

    //Make all the numbered pages:

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
    {
        if($i != $current_page)
        {
            echo '<a href="profile.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '&' . http_build_query($_GET) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
        }
        else {
                 echo $i . ' ';
             }
    }//END FOR LOOP

    // If it's not the last page, make a Next button:

    if ($current_page != $pages)
    {
        echo '<a href="profile.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&' . http_build_query($_GET) . '"> Next</a>';
    }

    echo '</p>'; 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if $_GET contains s or p you you would end-up with doubling those:

```
$clean = $_GET;
unset($clean['p']);    
unset($clean['s']);
echo '/someurl?' . http_build_query($clean);
```

Something like that should work